# Trouble with google collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am facing a problem with google colab :

I have this error :

`TypeError: makedirs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'`

And I saw that it means that I am using python 2.x

However, `! python -V` returns Python 3.7.12

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Is that function imported from the `os` library? It should work, I have done that with `os.makedirs(dir_datos_input, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: Yes, actually I am facing this problem while using kaggle in order to import datasets to work with for ML :)

Comment: So, you are facing this problem in Google Collab and also in Kaggle?